# How to implement an equivalent version of Adaboost in OpenCV and SciKit-learn?

Tags: opencv, machine-learning, scikit-learn, computer-vision, adaboost

Basically, I have the following in C++ (OpenCV):

```
CvMLData cvml ...

CvBoost boost;
boost.train(&cvml, CvBoostParams(CvBoost::REAL, 1000, 0, 1, false, 0), false);
```

and the following in Python (SciKit-learn):

```
bdt = AdaBoostClassifier(DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=1),
                         #algorithm="SAMME.R",
                         n_estimators=1000)
bdt.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

How do I make them similar (or equivalent)?

Right now, I get a low test error with OpenCV (< 10%) and a high one in SciKit-Learn (> 40%, so almost random)

Answer (score 1):

Both adaboost and decision trees have several parameters which can influence the final result greatly.
To get similar classifiers you should use similar parameters - for example in your C++ code you are using 1000 weak estimators versus 100 in your python code.

Look into the difference between the two implementations of adaboost and decision trees and try to change your parameters to match as much as possible.

Also if your aim is to lower test error and not necessarily get two equivalent classifiers you could simply optimize your preferred classifier instead of getting them perfectly aligned.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo in my example, it is the same in my code. I am trying to put the same parameters in both classifiers, and I have read the documentation to do so; so far everything seems to be matching.